# T-SQL Running Monthly Totals Including Missing Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this sounds really simple but I just cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have a temporary table that holds for example, Handler, MonthName, MonthNumber and MTD, which is a total for that month. What I need to do with that data is then create a running total for each Handler, from April to March. Now, here is the bit I am struggling with. Not all Handlers will have data for all months.

For example.

```
Handler              MonthName       MonthNo          MTD
Julian Slaughter     April           1                10000
Julian Slaughter     June            3                12000
Julian Slaughter     July            4                10000
Julian Slaughter     September       6                12000
Bob Monkhouse        April           1                5000
Bob Monkhouse        July            4                5000
```

So I want the results to look like this

```
Julian Slaughter     April           1                10000
Julian Slaughter     May             2                10000
Julian Slaughter     June            3                22000
Julian Slaughter     July            4                32000
Julian Slaughter     August          5                32000
Julian Slaughter     September       6                44000
```

...and so on until March

```
Bob Monkhouse        April           1                5000
Bob Monkhouse        May             2                5000
Bob Monkhouse        June            3                5000
Bob Monkhouse        July            4                10000
```

...and so on until March

I have tried `LEFT JOIN` onto a table of the Month Names\Numbers and I have had an attempt at

```
OVER(PARTITION ..... ORDER BY ..... RANGE\ROWS)
```

but can't get the missing months.

Thanks in advance, sorry for the poor formatting, not sure how to do tables on here.

EDIT - Here is my LEFT JOIN attempt

```
SELECT
Months.MonthNo,
Department,
Executive,
#8.MonthNo,
MTD = SUM([TY MTD Prem]) OVER (PARTITION BY Department, Executive, [Exec Code] ORDER BY #8.MonthNo RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM Months
LEFT JOIN #8 ON Months.MonthNo = #8.MonthNo
```

For one Executive, I only get 4 rows, not the 12 I need. Can't show you the results for Data Protection purposes.

Comment: what sql server version are you using?

Comment: an outer join with a months table is the right way to go. Please consider editing your question with the dll + dml for the sample data so that people will be able to help you faster. Also, include your current sql query.

Comment: Post your attempt to outer join to the months table.   That's the correct approach, so we just need to debug what you did.

Comment: Tanner, I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Zohar, I have only included an example as the actual code is nearly 1,000 lines long as there are many temporary tables created to manipulate the data, hence the cut down version.

Comment: So, you have to join table with missing months...

Comment: Here is my LEFT JOIN attempt

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to add your left join attempt.  Comments are not good places to try to post code.

Comment: Do you really have to do this at the DB level? It looks like something the application can handle quite easily.

Comment: Luaan, there is no application.The data that I work with is provided as an extract for a proprietary system to allow the end user to use ANY industry standard tool to manipulate the data.

Comment: here is some test data guys http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80fdc/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @start_date date, @end_date date
SELECT @start_date='2012-04-01',@end_date='2013-03-31'
;WITH xo AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS cte_start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)
    FROM xo
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date) <= @end_date   
), x as (
    select *,row_number() over (order by cte_start_date) monthno
  from xo
  )
,  y as (
  select distinct handler from test
)
SELECT y.handler, datename(mm,x.cte_start_date), x.monthno
,(select sum(mtd) from test a where a.handler=y.handler and a.monthno<=x.monthno) mtd
FROM y
cross join x
order by 1,3
```

see example on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d483/15

Comment: Good Answer with exact need.

Comment: Actually, I prefer answers with at least some text to explain what you did. Remember that the answer stays on SO for other people to read, so even if the OP understand your question just by looking at the code, other people might struggle with it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. The proposed solution worked a treat. I had to use the same code several times in various other parts of my giant query but it worked great.